# How to update server response in UI using MVVM pattern

Tags: java, android, android-viewmodel

I am using MVVM pattern in my app I have separate repository class for network operations. In repository class I am getting response from the server. How can I show Toast message send from the server in my main activity.

Below is my code:

**Repository.java**

```
public class MyRepository {

MutableLiveData<List<Facts>> mutableLiveData = new MutableLiveData<>();
    
Application application;

public MyRepository(Application application) {
    this.application = application;
}

public MutableLiveData<List<Facts>> getMutableLiveData(){

    Retrofit retrofit = RetrofitClient.getInstance();
    ApiService apiService = retrofit.create(ApiService.class);

    apiService.getFacts().subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                         .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                         .subscribe(new Observer<List<Facts>>() {
                             @Override
                             public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {

                             }

                             @Override
                             public void onNext(List<Facts> facts) {

                                 if(facts.size() > 0 && facts != null){

                                     mutableLiveData.setValue(facts);
                                 }
                             }

                             @Override
                             public void onError(Throwable e) {

                                 TastyToast.makeText(application,e.getMessage(),TastyToast.LENGTH_SHORT,
                                         TastyToast.ERROR).show();
                             }

                             @Override
                             public void onComplete() {

                             }
                         });

       return mutableLiveData;
  }
 }
```

**FactsViewModel.java**

```
public class FactsViewModel extends AndroidViewModel {

MyRepository repo;

public FactsViewModel(@NonNull Application application) {
    super(application);

    repo = new MyRepository(application);
  }

public LiveData<List<Facts>> getAllFacts(){

    return repo.getMutableLiveData();
  }
}
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
 private void myFacts(){

    FactsViewModel viewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(FactsViewModel.class);  

    viewModel.getAllFacts().observe(this, new Observer<List<Facts>>() {
       @Override
       public void onChanged(List<Facts> facts) {

           adapter = new FactsAdapter(facts,getActivity());
           recycle.setAdapter(adapter);
       }
   });

}
```

How can I show error toast messages in `MainActivity`?

Comment: You have to get the response which contains the toast from your server and then simply show it in your mainactivity

Comment: How explain it  I am fetching toast message in repository how can I get message in `MainActivity` from there.

Comment: did you get the toast from your server ?

Comment: yeah when I get error message  from the server it shows in MainaAtivity but progress bar keeps on showing it should be hide.

Comment: After showing the toast , you have to simply hide or set the progressbar visibility t ogone

Comment: Thats the only problem how can I update UI in repository class where I am getting Toast from the server look at my code above.

Comment: what are you using to fetch data , i  mean how are you observing the data , are you using rxjava ?

Comment: Yeah i am using rxjava

Comment: but where do you have the progress bar launched from , your main activity ?

Comment: Yeah I have progress bar defined in `MainActivity`

Comment: so if i get what you mean you want to show  toast message bsed on the status from the server , if data is loading , success and failure , is that what you want ?

Comment: yeah exactly if there is no data on server then based in that i  am showing some image and if data is present then I am showing recycler view.

Comment: Alright the way i did this before in my project is by using generic class which has some enumerations , i ll share some code with you and you can check it out and change it based on your situation

Comment: please explain with code I have hard time finding out  this

Answer (score 1):

To implement that you firstly need to create a class which has the status of the response ,
Loading which is before the fetching of the data and there you can set progress bar to visible then on success you would set the data to your adapter and right after your hide your progress bar and in the on failure one , you show the toast message error

- This is the generic class

```
class AuthResource<T>(
    var authStatus : AuthStatus? = null,
    var data : T,
    var msg : String? = null

)

fun <T> success(@Nullable data: T): AuthResource<T> {
    return AuthResource(
        AuthStatus.Success,
        data,
        null
    )
}

fun <T> Error(@NonNull msg: String?, @Nullable data: T) : AuthResource<T>? {
    return AuthResource(
        AuthStatus.ERROR,
        data,
        msg
    )
}

fun <T> loading(@Nullable data: T): AuthResource<T>? {
    return AuthResource(
        AuthStatus.LOADING,
        data,
        null
    )
}


enum class AuthStatus {
    Success, ERROR, LOADING
}
```

- This is my view model where i implement the authResource with the api response

```
class MainViewModel @Inject constructor( private var webAuth: WebAuth,
    private var favFoodDao: FavFoodDao,
    private var application: Application) : ViewModel() {

    /// you have to create MediatorLiveData with authresource which contains your modelclass 

    private var mediatorLiveData = MediatorLiveData<AuthResource<WrapLatestMeals>>()
    
    ///Here you return a livedata object 
    fun ObserverCountries(): LiveData<AuthResource<WrapCountries>> {
        var liveData = LiveDataReactiveStreams.fromPublisher(
            webAuth.getCountries()
                 ///onerrorreturn , rxjava operator which returns error in case 
                 ///of response failure 
                .onErrorReturn(object : Function<Throwable, WrapCountries> {
                    override fun apply(t: Throwable): WrapCountries {
                        var country = WrapCountries()
                        return country
                    }
                })
                .map(object : Function<WrapCountries, 
                     AuthResource<WrapCountries>> {
                    override fun apply(t: WrapCountries): 
                        AuthResource<WrapCountries> {
                        if(t.meals.isNullOrEmpty())
                        {
                            return Error(
                                "Error",
                                t
                            )!!
                        }
                        return success(t)
                    }
                })
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        )

       
        //add that data to mediatorLivedata 
        mediatorLiveDataCountries.addSource(liveData, Observer {
            mediatorLiveDataCountries.postValue(it)
            mediatorLiveDataCountries.removeSource(liveData)
        })
        return mediatorLiveDataCountries

    }
```

- This is how you handle the status in your MainActivity

```
 mainViewModel = ViewModelProvider(this,provider)[MainViewModel::class.java]
        mainViewModel.ObserverCountries().observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
             when(it.authStatus) {
                 AuthStatus.LOADING -> /// here you show progressbar in response pre-fetch
                 {
                     
                     countriesFragmentBinding.countryprogress.show()
                 }
                 AuthStatus.Success -> { // here you update your ui

                     countriesAdapter = CountriesAdapter(it.data.meals!!, 
                     requireContext())
                     countriesFragmentBinding.recyclercountries.adapter = countriesAdapter
                     countriesAdapter!!.deleteCategory(23)
                     countriesFragmentBinding.countryprogress.hide()
                 }
                 AuthStatus.ERROR -> // here you hide your progressbar and show your toast
                 {
                   
                     countriesFragmentBinding.countryprogress.hide()
                     ToastyError(requireContext(),getString(R.string.errorretreivingdata))
                 }

             }
        })

        return countriesFragmentBinding.root
    }

}
```